# UseDeveloperExceptionPage MoveNext not showing file and line

Tags: asp.net-core

The file and the line where the exception occurs is not being displayed on the Developer exception page in the browser.

The exception page shows:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> Exception: Something went wrong! MoveNext
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers
>
> Exception: Something went wrong!
>
> MoveNext
>       ThrowForNonSuccess
>
> HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>
> MoveNext

MoveNext does not display the file or line where the error occurs. It is also not shown when expanding the Show raw exceptions details:

> System.Exception: Something went wrong!
>
> at
>   OdeToFood.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()

THis is my `Startup` class:

```
public class Startup
{
    ...
    public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app,
        IHostingEnvironment env,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IGreeter greeter )
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();

        if (env.IsDevelopment()) // Register this first
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseWelcomePage(new WelcomePageOptions
        {
            Path = "/welcome"
        });

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");
            var message = greeter.GetGreeting();
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(message);
        });
```

How do I get it to display the file and line number?

> Startup.cs     55.      throw new Exception("Something went
>   wrong!");

Using Visual Studio Professional 2015,
IIS Express,
Chrome and IE,
Windows 7 Enterprise

It fails with or without debugging.

Comment: How do you launch the app? IIS Express or something else?

Comment: I'm taking Scott Allen's aspdotnet core fundamentals course and using IIS Express as he does.

Comment: I test the code and it works. Make to launch it without debugging

Comment: You can go to the course discussions directly and address your issue => https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspdotnet-core-fundamentals/discussion

Comment: It fails with or without debugging.  This question is not course specific and I'm addressing it to the stackflow community.